# Jacoco coverage report in gitlab-ci for Android project reports "No class files specified"

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, jacoco

I set up a Jacoco coverage report for our Kotlin Android project, which is supposed to run in gitlab-ci as job. I followed [this article](https://blog.gouline.net/code-coverage-on-android-with-jacoco-92ec90c9355e) to generate the gradle tasks.
The coverage report works perfectly if run locally. But if the same gradle task is executed in the gitlab runner, it always produces empty reports with the message "No class files specified".

What's different in the pipeline when it comes to class files?

Maybe one of you is able to spot the issue.

*jacoco.gradle*:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            jacoco {
                includeNoLocationClasses = true
            }
        }
    }

    jacoco {
        version = '0.8.4'
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    def buildTypes = android.buildTypes.collect { type ->
        type.name
    }
    def productFlavors = android.productFlavors.collect { flavor ->
        flavor.name
    }
    if (!productFlavors) productFlavors.add('')
    productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
        buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->
            def sourceName, sourcePath
            if (!productFlavorName) {
                sourceName = sourcePath = "${buildTypeName}"
            } else {
                sourceName = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName.capitalize()}"
                sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}${buildTypeName}"
            }
            def testTaskName = "test${sourceName.capitalize()}UnitTest"

            task "${testTaskName}Coverage" (type:JacocoReport, dependsOn: "$testTaskName") {
                group = "Reporting"
                description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports on the ${sourceName.capitalize()} build."
                classDirectories = fileTree(
                    dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/${sourcePath}",
                    excludes: ['**/R.class'] #List of excludes is reduced for this question
                )
                def coverageSourceDirs = [
                    "$project.buildDir.parent/src/main/java",
                    "$project.buildDir.parent/src/$productFlavorName/java",
                    "$project.buildDir.parent/src/$buildTypeName/java"
                ]

                additionalSourceDirs = files(coverageSourceDirs)
                sourceDirectories = files(coverageSourceDirs)
                executionData = files("${project.buildDir}/jacoco/${testTaskName}.exec")

                reports {
                    xml.enabled = true
                    html.enabled = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*gitlab-ci.yml*: (unrelated jobs and stages removed)

```
image: docker:latest

variables:
    BUILDER_VERSION: "68e9780a"
    GRADLE_ARGS_CI: "--no-daemon --stacktrace"

stages:
    - build
    - test

.build-template: &build_definition
    stage: build
    image: our-docker-registry.com/android-builder:$BUILDER_VERSION
    tags:
        - frontend
    only:
        - merge_requests
        - develop
        - schedules

.test-template: &test_definition
    stage: test
    image: our-docker-registry.com/android-builder:$BUILDER_VERSION
    tags:
        - hermine-frontend
    only:
        - merge_requests
        - develop
        - schedules

build:dev:debug:
    <<: *build_definition
    script:
        - echo "Starting SCRIPT in job $CI_JOB_NAME"
        - ./gradlew $GRADLE_ARGS_CI :app:assembleDevDebug
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - app/build/outputs/apk/dev/debug
            - app/build/tmp/
        expire_in: 1 week

test:dev:debug:
    <<: *test_definition
    script:
        - echo "Starting SCRIPT in job $CI_JOB_NAME"
        - ./gradlew $GRADLE_ARGS_CI -Pci --console=plain :app:testDevDebugUnitTest
        - ./gradlew $GRADLE_ARGS_CI -Pci --console=plain :app:testDevDebugUnitTestCoverage
    artifacts:
        paths:
            - app/build/reports/tests/testDevDebugUnitTest
            - app/build/jacoco #execution file
            - app/build/reports
        expire_in: 1 day
```

Screenshot of my Android Studio `build` folder:
[image]

Comment: Can you please help me on the same problem, please check the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/64641302/3946958